# Transforming a Groovy Map

Tags: groovy

This is my Map

```
[a: 1, b: 1, c: 2, d: 2, e: 1, f: 2]
```

I want to group similar values and get:

```
[1: [a, b, e], 2: [c, d, f]]
```

My best effort is

```
myMap.groupBy{it.value}.collectEntries{key, value -> [(key): value.keySet()]}
```

Anything that is groov'ier?

Comment: What you have already is already simple and elegant? You can still refine it to `map.groupBy { it.value }.collectEntries { [it.key, it.value*.key ] }` to get the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code:

```
def result = [a: 1, b: 1, c: 2, d: 2, e: 1, f: 2].inject([:].withDefault {[]}) { a, k, v ->
 a[v] << k 
 a
}

println result
```

prints:

```
[1:[a, b, e], 2:[c, d, f]]
```

this uses the groovy [Map.inject](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#inject(java.lang.Object,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) method which is similar to foldLeft or reduce in other languages and the groovy [Map.withDefault](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#withDefault(groovy.lang.Closure)) method so that when you access a map and a key is not found, a default value of empty list (`[]`) is returned.

Explanation:

- `.inject(` - go through the map one key-value pair at a time
- `[:].withDefault {[]}` - starting with an empty map which will return an empty list if you access a key that does not exist
- `) { a, k, v -` for each key-value pair, do something with the initial map `a`
- `a[v] << k` - specifically, add the incoming key as an element in a list (as returned by withDefault) contained in the map under key `v`.
- `a` - return the modified map so that it is sent in as `a` in `{a, k, v ->` in the next iteration

Answer (score 0):

What you have already is already simple and elegant. You can still refine it to

```
map.groupBy { it.value }.collectEntries { [it.key, it.value*.key ] }
```

to get the same result.